# not sure if this is my mistake ~~ vs2010 Add Service Reference fails

Tags: wcf, visual-studio-2010, soap

https://tbe.taleo.net/MANAGER/dispatcher/servlet/rpcrouter

the above is from Taleo's API guide.
I'm trying to create a WCF Client
(e.g.:  " Creating Your First WCF Client"
   http://channel9.msdn.com/shows/Endpoint/Endpoint-Screencasts-Creating-Your-First-WCF-Client/  )

The tbe.taleo... link is from Taleo's API documentation.

Likely my understanding is flawed.  My assumption is that when the
link from Taleo is entered into the vs2010 "Add Service Reference"
dialog and **GO** is clicked, then vs2010 should retrieve
a proper WSDL/SOAP envelope back from the Taleo link.
That ***does not*** happen; instead an error occurs.
Fiddler2 (http://fiddler2.com) displays the status code 500
"HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error".  [FULL DETAILS BELOW]

"**WcfTestClient.exe**" gives a similar error:  [WcfTestClient DETAILS BELOW]

**QUESTION:**  is it me, or is the Taleo link flawed?

Thank you,
Gerry

**[FULL DETAILS "Add Service Reference"]**
The HTML document does not contain Web service discovery information.
Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'https://tbe.taleo.net/MANAGER/dispatcher/servlet/rpcrouter'.
The content type text/xml;charset=utf-8 of the response message does not match the content type of the binding (application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8). If using a custom encoder, be sure that the IsContentTypeSupported method is implemented properly. The first 544 bytes of the response were: '



SOAP-ENV:Protocol
Unsupported content type "application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8", must be: "text/xml".
/MANAGER/dispatcher/servlet/rpcrouter

'.
The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.
If the service is defined in the current solution, try building the solution and adding the service reference again.

**[WcfTestClient DETAILS]**
Error: Cannot obtain Metadata from https://tbe.taleo.net/MANAGER/dispatcher/servlet/rpcrouter If this is a Windows (R) Communication Foundation service to which you have access, please check that you have enabled metadata publishing at the specified address.  For help enabling metadata publishing, please refer to the MSDN documentation at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=65455.WS-Metadata Exchange Error    URI: https://tbe.taleo.net/MANAGER/dispatcher/servlet/rpcrouter    Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'https://tbe.taleo.net/MANAGER/dispatcher/servlet/rpcrouter'.    The content type text/xml;charset=utf-8 of the response message does not match the content type of the binding (application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8). If using a custom encoder, be sure that the IsContentTypeSupported method is implemented properly. The first 544 bytes of the response were: 'SOAP-ENV:ProtocolUnsupported content type "application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8", must be: "text/xml"./MANAGER/dispatcher/servlet/rpcrouter'.    The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.HTTP GET Error    URI: https://tbe.taleo.net/MANAGER/dispatcher/servlet/rpcrouter    The HTML document does not contain Web service discovery information.

Comment: You have to ask the vendor for the URL to their WSDL or metadata. It's not always "serviceUrl?WSDL".

Comment: thank you John, my fault; I've failed to understand Taleo's documentation while at the same time trying to mimic what Aaron Skonnard's tutorial at http://channel9.msdn.com/shows/Endpoint/Endpoint-Screencasts-Creating-Your-First-WCF-Client/ was demonstrating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly, I can only blame myself.  I watched the excellent free Pluralsight videos.
I tried to sort it out from Taleo's documentation, Google, msdn, et cetera.

I should have used this:
http://tbe.taleo.net/wsdl/DispatcherAPI.wsdl
from here:
http://tbe.taleo.net/products/TBE_API_Guide.pdf   from
http://www.taleo.com/solutions/taleo-business-edition-web-integration-api

Thanks to all who gave some thought to this issue.
g.

Comment: f.y.i. I've added some useful Taleo generic information here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5571245/etl-of-human-resource-data-from-taleo

Answer (score 1):

Browsing to the Taleo link, I get

> SOAP RPC Router
>
> Sorry, I don't speak via HTTP GET- you
>   have to use HTTP POST to talk to me.

My suspicion is that both Visual Studio and Fiddler do an HTTP GET to retrieve the WSDL (a description of the Web Service). Instead, they're getting an HTML error message.

Adding "?WSDL" to the URL didn't help. So I'd say the Taleo link is not intended to be used in this manner, but instead is designed for [SOAP RPC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_State_Transfer#SOAP_RPC_contrast).

Answer (score 0):

You are not to be blamed. The Taleo documentation is a bit confusing. Especially with respect to the URL to be used.

For a detailed description check out [Taleo Integration in Drupal](http://drupalden.blogspot.com/2011/06/drupal-taleo-integration-with.html)